# Timeouts and Freezing in EWS with Office 365

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, exchangewebservices

I have a service that watches 2 email inboxes. One thread is created for each inbox. The new messages are read and marked as Read on startup, then the NewMail event handler handles all new mail after that.

We have been using EWS version 14. We had no issues retrieving emails.

After we moved the emails to Office 365, the problems started.

On startup, the retrieval and handling of existing new messages is still working fine.

After startup, when the NewMail event handler is triggered, the bind/load method times out, regardless of what we set the Timeout property to.

We tried to switch to the newest EWS version (15.0).

With the new version, the startup handling still works fine.

However, trying to bind one email in the NewMail event handler makes no error, but makes the inbox thread quit.

When there is a new email message in both inboxes, the entire service freezes on the Bind line (i let it sit for 40 minutes before having to kill the service).

We tried both EWS versions with the following, with no success:

The below code is used in the NewEmail event handler AND the startup processing of existing new messages. Why would the same code have issues in one place and not the other? How do i fix this?

I have also tried to use EmailMessage.Bind using the NotificationEventArgs object, but i have the same issues.

We tried a SyncLock to get around the lock up and/or timeout, but that did not help.
Thanks!

```
 Private Sub HaveMail(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.NotificationEventArgs)
    Dim error_occured As Boolean = False
    Try
        Try
            SyncLock lock
                Logger.LogDebug("Just entered the Locked state of the HaveMail event")
                Dim ir As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, False), New ItemView(20))

                Do While ir.Items.Count > 0
                    For Each i As EmailMessage In ir
                        Try
                            Logger.LogDebug("About to load a newly received email message")
                            i.Load(PropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Throw New Exception("Error while loading an email message: " & ex.Message)
                        End Try
                        Dim rm As New ReceivedMessage
                        rm.ReceivedDateTime = i.DateTimeReceived
                        rm.ToAddress = i.DisplayTo
                        rm.Subject = i.Subject
                        rm.Body = i.Body
                        rm.FromAddress = i.From.Address
                        Logger.LogDebug("Just loaded a newly received email message from " & rm.FromAddress)
                        Dim rme As New ReceivedMessageEvent
                        rme.msg = rm
                        RaiseEvent GotMail(Me, rme)
                        Logger.LogDebug("Just processed a newly received email message from " & rm.FromAddress)
                        i.IsRead = True
                        i.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite)
                    Next
                    ir = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, False), New ItemView(20))
                Loop

            End SyncLock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to an answer on my posting on MSN, I was able to fix the problem.
I needed to raise the DefaultConnectionLimit to 100. Apparently, it defaults to 2, which was not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's not a good practice to do much of anything from within the actual event handler.  So Update, FindItems, and Bind would all make a call back to EWS from within your handler, and that is not good.  The ExchangeService object is also not thread safe.  How did you get away with it before O365?  I have no answer other than just lucky.